# The value of the object in the request always null in wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, json.net

I have a WCF service and the client website to test the service. The WCF service doesn't get the value of the object. I have searched the web and modified my code. However I haven't solved it. Would someone help me. Thanks in advance.

There is my service:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,          
       UriTemplate = "BookInfo/")]

    BookingResult Booking(BookInfo bookInfo);


 public BookingResult Booking(BookInfo bookInfo)
    {
        BookingResult result = new BookingResult();            
        if (bookInfo.Name == null)
        {
            result.isSucceed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.isSucceed = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

There is the method in my website to call the service.

```
using Booking; //this is WCF service reference
private string callService(BookInfo input)
    {

        string serviceUrl = "http://localhost:1599026/Booking.svc/BookInfo/";            
        string stringPayload = "{\"bookInfo\":[" +JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input) +"]}";           
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";                    
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string rtn = client.UploadString(serviceUrl,"POST", stringPayload);
        return rtn;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get your error information, could you please share with me? Have you configured and published the WCF web-mode service correctly? I copy your code and host the web-mode service on the IIS, finally I succeed to access the method.  I suggest that you could expose the default GetData() method and then test it whether you could get the returned results correctly, and then we test the strongly-typed method.

Here is my demo, wish it is useful to you.

**IService1.cs**

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
   UriTemplate = "BookInfo/")]
    BookingResult Booking(BookInfo bookInfo);
}
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public BookingResult Booking(BookInfo bookInfo)
    {
        BookingResult result = new BookingResult();
        if (bookInfo==null)
        {
            result.isSucceed = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.isSucceed = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

}
[DataContract]
public class BookInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class BookingResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool isSucceed { get; set; }
```

}

**Webconfig**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService4.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="svbehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService4.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbehavior">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="svbehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webbehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Result.

*GetMethod.*
[image: GetData Method]

*Booking Method.*
[image: Booking Method]

Feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have five methods on the service and their  BodyStyle is  WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Those methods can get the value and post the result correctly. I debug the method in service so I confirmed the method is called. Your webconfig has two endpoint. Mine is only one.

Comment: I read my code again. The client app got correctly result using HttpWebRequest. The client app used WebClient. Do you have any idea where I need to look for? By the way, in your example webconfig, you have two endpoint. Do I need to have endpoint for every method in service?

Comment: There is no need to add additional MEX endpoint. I suggest you use  the Fiddler to compare the two request information(use the machinename instead of localhost URL so that the fiddler could grap the localhost request).

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the payload you are sending to the service. Change

`string stringPayload = "{\"bookInfo\":[" +JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input) +"]}";`

to

**`string stringPayload = "{\"bookInfo\":" +JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input) +"}";`**

(notice there is no need to wrap JSON value inside **[]**)and your `WebClient` request will be working and your service will have a non-null value for the arguments.